# MySql JSON nested array value comparation (greater / lower) in WHERE

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

MySQL 5.7

MySQL JSON field contains key "a" which contains array of JSON objects with keys "c" and it values. How to format JSON_EXTRACT path parameter to get greater compare (greater or lower) those "c" values with @v in WHERE part of SELECT statement?

If we compare key "d" ( '$.d') > @v ) for different values of @v it will work like a charm, but it never work the same way with nested array object key.

If we try to compare key "c" values of each object in array, it always return true '$.a[*].c') > @v in case that there are ARRAY and INTEGER types comparing. According to MySQL manual, INTEGER have lower priority then ARRAY type.

The question is how to compare each value of "c" with @v and find only records with JSON field, which contains a greater or lower values of key "c".

```
SET @v = 70;
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'a', 
        JSON_ARRAY(
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 25),
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 70), 
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 35),
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 30),
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 17.5),
            JSON_OBJECT('c', 
                JSON_ARRAY(
                    JSON_OBJECT('c', 35),
                    JSON_OBJECT('c', 30)
                )
            )
        ),
        'b',
        70
    ),
'$.a[*].c') > @v
;
```

To make a question clear let's search the records with prices greater then $70 in the next record-set:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test` (`data`) VALUES 
    ('
        {
            "node": 1,
            "orders": [
                {
                    "ts": "Jan 13, 2016 04:38pm",
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "Qty": 1,
                            "SKU": 1,
                            "price": 40,
                            "total": 40
                        },
                        {
                            "Qty": 2,
                            "SKU": 2,
                            "price": 80,
                            "total": 160
                        },
                        {
                            "Qty": 5,
                            "SKU": 3,
                            "price": 10,
                            "total": 50
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    '),
    ('
        {
            "node": 2,
            "orders": [
                {
                    "ts": "Jan 13, 2016 04:38pm",
                    "order_id": 2,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "Qty": 3,
                            "SKU": 1,
                            "price": 40,
                            "total": 120
                        },
                        {
                            "Qty": 1,
                            "SKU": 3,
                            "price": 10,
                            "total": 10
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ');
```

Select statement that works:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` 
WHERE `data`->'$.node' > 1;
```

and that should works, but don't:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` 
WHERE `data`->'$.orders[*].order_id' > 1;

SELECT * FROM `test` 
WHERE `data`->'$.orders[*].products[*].price' > 50;

SELECT * FROM `test` 
WHERE `data`->'$.orders[*].products[*].total' < 30;
```

Comment: MySQL does not have any JSON functions to support your use cases. One way to do this would be to create functions that return the GREATEST (or LEAST) member of an array, and use that for comparison, but since those functions don't exist you would need to write your own stored function or UDF.

Comment: @IkeWalker, thank you for your support. I was ready for such answer, but even if it will be a function, how to make it right? I mean that MySQL have no arrays, so how to compare values of field contained: '[12, 34, 56, 78]' without string parsing?

Comment: Since the array is a JSON object, you can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` to extract the elements one by one, but that would be hard to code into a function because I believe you need to use literal values for the path, so you can't use a variable.